# How to get instance from a class

Tags: java, instance

My main class this is :

```
private Integer id;

private String code;
private static Main instance;

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    saveDefaultConfig();
    reload();
}

public void reload() {
    id = 20;
    code = "code";
}

public Integer getID() {
    return id;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public Main() {
    instance = this;
}
```

And on my other class im trying to getID and getCode
This is my code for getting the code and id.
the reload() method is called onEnable (starting)

```
Main main = new Main();
System.out.println(main.getCode());
```

and it returns null.

Comment: are you calling `reload()` before calling `getCode()`? Because you are initializing that in `reload()` method.

Comment: Do you mind posting `onEnable()` and how you call it?

Comment: This is a plugin for a program, onEnable get called when plugin starts. and reload() is called before getCode()

Comment: It gets called when plugin starts, not on instances you create.

Comment: I would just like to say that classes that define mutable objects with methods that "reinitialize" or reset them, as your reload() method appears to do, are a poor programming practice.  You should aspire to never write classes like this.

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables are initialized to default values--0 for `int`, `false` for `boolean`, etc. Object references are initialized to `null`.

So in your sample, the `String` reference `code` is initialized to `null`. You never do anything to change that before you print it out. That's why you see a `null.'

I do like how you started your question: "My main class this is." It's like seeing a post on Stack Overflow from Yoda.

Comment: I added the onEnable method, which gets called when plugin starts and reload() method sets code and id. btw whos Yoda?

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the fact that your variables are not set. I am assuming that you want for reload to be called, so you may just want to go ahead and set up a constructor that calls reload like this:

```
public Main()
{
     reload();
}
```

Comment: No reload() does get called when plugin starts.

Comment: I don't see that anywhere in your code... Are you calling it somewhere you didn't post?

Comment: Alright i changed it, the OnEnabled method gets called when the plugin starts

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to check to be sure that "onEnable()" gets called and not "OnEnabled".